# Math calculation for angle between two points Java

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to make a calculation for an angle between my mouse and the 'player' Im using lwjgl and opengl. This is what is use to rotate the image:

```
GL11.glTranslatef(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth()/2, p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight()/2, 0);
GL11.glRotated(0, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
GL11.glTranslatef(-p.getPosition().x+-playerTexture.getTextureWidth()/2, -p.getPosition().y+-playerTexture.getTextureHeight()/2, 0);`
```

I have tried two things but everytime it just keeps spinning the image non stop. My attempts:

```
public float getAngle(Player p) {
    float angle = (float) (Math.atan2(Mouse.getY() - 
    p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight()/2 , Mouse.getX() - 
    p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth()/2));
    return angle;
}

public void calcAngle(Player p){
    double y = Mouse.getY() - p.getPosition().y;
    double x = Mouse.getX() - p.getPosition().x;
    double dir = Math.atan2(y, x);
}
```

I hope someone knows a fix for this. Thanks.

Comment: Im calling the code in the render void and I don't have any stop code?

Comment: What do you want to do actually? rotate the player based on the angle difference between your mouse and player? Rotate towards the mouse or away?. And you shouldn't call it in the render code. Don't mix up rendering with input handling. LWJGL 3 uses glfw for input handling and it has callbacks, you can check up on that. If you call it in the render code it's gonna rotate every frame probably.

Comment: Yes exactly that! I don't want it to rotate every frame. Where do I call it to not rotate every frame?
Btw: I'm trying to rotate it towards the mouse.

Comment: If you can show the part of the code where you are calling it, maybe we can help more. I think you are calling it in a function that is for drawing so it's called every frame. Like every frame there is a loop that does this `clear -> draw -> update` you are probably calling it inside this loop. What you want to do is set up a mouse or keyboard callback and use `glfwpollevents()` so it's called only when the mouse moves or a certain key is pressed

Answer (score 0):

I can't see where you're actually using your `getAngle` method, but I suspect you're using the angle calculated from `Math.atan2` directly in the openGL rotate function?

If that's the case, I would guess you've got a mixup of units. I believe `Math.atan2` returns radians, and openGL expects degrees. Try using `Math.toDegrees(angle)`.

However, I'd expect this to show really tiny angles rather than spinning like mad...

First thing I'd do to diangose the issue is write the angle into the console. Is it 0, 90, 180 etc, or 0, 1.723, 3.1431 etc?

Comment: Already tried the first thing you mentioned. doesn't work. And second at what point of the mouse you want me to write the angle of the mouse?

Comment: I'd just put it after it was calculated. It should just stream it out loads into the console, and you can position the mouse at a known angle to the player and it should read an appropriate value.

Comment: Your code is a bit confusing, as none of it seems connected. You have two methods to calculate angle doing nearly the same thing, neither of which look to be used! `calcAngle` doesn't even return anything

Comment: No problem. Get anywhere with console out? What happens if you put a "set" angle in your OpenGL transofrm? Say you put in "45", does that make it rotate 45 degrees? If that works, and the console out of the angle is showing "45" too there's an issue in how things are fitting together

Comment: Okay i'll try that. I know that this sounds like a noob question but how do i make that only run once? instead of that it keeps looping on 45 degrees. And I don't know how I would make that output in  console

Comment: Don't bother making it only run once. If it sets the angle 100 times, but always to 45 degrees that's fine. Setting it to 45 degrees is to test that the OpenGL is doing what you expect - no console needed. To console the value of angle you just need `System.out.println(angle)`

Comment: All it does is spin very fast. Do you maybe know whats causing this? I can send all my code if you want

Comment: The line where you set the angle to 45 would be useful. That it's spinning and you're not using your angle-calculation rules out that the problem was with calculating angle - it's with setting it.

Comment: This is what im using:   GL11.glRotated(45, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
Where should I place it?

Comment: If you remove it completely does it stop spinning?

Comment: Yes. I'm also using   GL11.glTranslatef(p.getPosition().x+playerTexture.getTextureWidth()/2, p.getPosition().y+playerTexture.getTextureHeight()/2, 0);
  GL11.glTranslatef(-p.getPosition().x+-playerTexture.getTextureWidth()/2, -p.getPosition().y+-playerTexture.getTextureHeight()/2, 0); To make it rotate around it's own center.

Comment: If you put `GL11.glRotated(1, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);` does it rotate much slower? The rotation could be adding the transform onto the previous rotation (rather than setting the 'absolute' rotation). If this is the case a lower number will make it spin slower, higher number would make it spin faster.

Comment: Well, it's getting beyond my experience (I don't know openGL stuff). But the issue is in the wider code/loop. How are you looping? Do you open and close your openGL transformation for each loop?

Comment: These are terms that I don't really know. I made a pastebin with all my code if that helps?https://pastebin.com/qndnsvPw

Comment: Might be worth making a new quesiton tagged with OpenGL asking why your rotation transform is being applied once-per-frame? (rather than this question asking why the angle calculaiton is wrong).

Comment: Yes I will. Shall I inlcude my pastebin in that post?

Comment: I'd include the code directly in your question (generally, it's better not to link to external stuff, it probably won't be there in a year etc, also I can't access things like that on my work network).

Comment: Okay, I have to wait 4 days before posting again tho :/

Comment: 4 days? Really? I didn't think it was that harsh. Try now, I gave you a rep and you're over 10 now.

Comment: Still has the cooldown. Thanks for helping though i'll wait it's fine :)